JavaFX (Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found)
I'm having a problem with JavaFX on my Macbook Air which is using the M1 chip with the latest software version. I am using JDK 17.0.12 and using the SDK of 17.0.13. The problem is below:
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  es2, sw Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:283) at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:253) at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:268) at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:291) at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:163) at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:659) at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:410) at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:569) at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1091) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:95) at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125) at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840) Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:569) at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1091) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:280) at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:291) at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:163) at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:659) at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:410) at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364) ... 5 more
I have tried changing the version to JDK 21 but it didn't change anything and I am using Visual Studio Code. I downloaded JavaFX from this website: https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/

Instructions on using JavaFX with VS Code are in the getting started instructions at openjfx.io.  Ensure you are using the aarch64 version of JavaFX (for M Macs) and not the x64 version (for Intel Macs).
